# There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard while inserting records to sqlite database?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I am developing an app in which i am getting data from server & saving that data to local sqlite database.But data is too much there are records in hundreds which i am inserting.At one point in inserting records to database my app gets below error message & get crashed.Plaese tell why this issue coming?

```
2016-04-02 16:59:41.406 [2057:107245] -[UIApplication endIgnoringInteractionEvents] called without matching -beginIgnoringInteractionEvents. Ignoring.
2016-04-02 16:59:41.535 [2057:107245] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/Users/apple/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/927CC377-23D5-4648-8D78-05B117A19C5C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1677AEC-3672-45EB-A80E-CAD2AEECB767/MyApp.app/Base.lproj/Main~iphone.storyboardc''
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the bundle target isn't universal. So make sure the Targeted Device Family in the bundle's build settings is set to iPhone AND iPad.

[image]